# How to protect Excel document from editing in AlaSQL

Tags: angularjs, alasql

I am using AlaSQL library to export JSON into an Excel workbook. I want the workbook to be read-only -- so that no-one can edit the contents of the cells, they can only read it. Is that possible in AlaSQL?

Comment: edited for legibility; you should include the code that you are currently using in the question.

Comment: It is not possible. Have a look at the xlsx-js lib - they might have it.